# Can't Reach Server Via SSH / HTTP But Ping / Traceroute Works?

Tags: networking, ping

I've been struggling with a weird problem for the last several days. I have a virtual dedicated server with IP address 184.154.111.243. Some machines on my local network have lost the ability to access it, or can only access it intermittently; however I can ping and traceroute it without issue. When I try to connect to a domain on the server (eg firestorm.coop) via SSH, I get "connect to host firestorm.coop port 22: Connection timed out". I've been using this server for a couple years and never had a problem before.

I've tried several troubleshooting steps including:

- disabling firewalls;
- connecting my computer directly to the Charter modem/router in my office;
- changing my LAN DNS (I've tried Charter's, Google's and OpenDNS);
- reinstalling my operating system;
- doing a factory reset on the Charter modem/router

I've spoken to the folks who maintain the server in question and they insist that everything is fine and I'm not being block listed. Also, the server seems to be accessible from everywhere other than my office. I've called Charter and they say that everything is fine on their end. I can't seem to identify a point of failure. To make the matter more bizarre, there are two computers on my LAN that can reach the server without problem.

Here is a traceroute from one of the affected machines:

```
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.791 ms  1.562 ms  1.953 ms
 2  * * *
 3  dtr02ahvlnc-tge-0-7-0-7.ahvl.nc.charter.com (96.34.66.49)  18.801 ms  18.809 ms  19.171 ms
 4  crr02ahvlnc-bue-100.ahvl.nc.charter.com (96.34.93.252)  18.779 ms  18.224 ms  16.942 ms
 5  crr02spbgsc-bue-400.spbg.sc.charter.com (96.34.66.239)  20.264 ms  21.252 ms  21.633 ms
 6  bbr01spbgsc-bue-4.spbg.sc.charter.com (96.34.2.50)  33.858 ms  16.897 ms  25.826 ms
 7  cha-b1-link.telia.net (213.248.98.25)  24.928 ms  25.409 ms  25.352 ms
 8  atl-b22-link.telia.net (62.115.120.184)  25.678 ms atl-b22-link.telia.net (62.115.115.215)  25.347 ms atl-b22-link.telia.net (62.115.138.38)  23.524 ms
 9  chi-b21-link.telia.net (62.115.116.111)  41.705 ms chi-b21-link.telia.net (62.115.116.105)  40.406 ms chi-b21-link.telia.net (62.115.116.103)  48.666 ms
 10  static.kpn.net (62.132.9.222)  50.931 ms  45.462 ms  40.246 ms
 11  agg1.c13.r14.s101.chi03.singlehop.net (67.212.190.230)  65.083 ms  64.806 ms  64.629 ms
 12  aswg1.c07.r06.s101.chi03.singlehop.net (96.127.188.171)  44.935 ms  45.405 ms  45.205 ms
 13  firestorm.coop (184.154.111.243)  43.653 ms  39.109 ms  43.443 ms
```

Can anyone recommend a next step for troubleshooting?

Comment: If you can access the server consistently from outside your LAN then it's a problem with the lan or a number of workstations. If two computers can always access it then you need to work out what's different about them - vlan / subnet, cable, router, network settings, etc. I don't think this is related to DNS or Ubuntu based on your question so I'm going to change your tags.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the quick reply. I've got two laptops both connected to the same router on my LAN. #1 is Debian and #2 is Mint. Neither machine could load a website on the server. Then both could reach the website for about twenty minutes, after which point #2 could connect but #1 could not. I swapped the ethernet cables so that #1 was plugged into the port previously used by #2 and flushed the caches, but no luck. Then ten minutes later, both machines could reach the site. During this entire time the site was accessible using my Android device on the same network. How is this even possible?

Comment: IP address conflict? Static IPs using DHCP ranges? That can cause similar problems. Otherwise one of the network guys may have some ideas.

Comment: You mention these are laptops you're having trouble with. Would it be possible to take one of them to a different location where you can connect to the Internet through a different ISP and observe whether the problem persists? That would help you determine if the problem is related to your client computer OR something to do with your ISP or LAN.

Comment: Thanks, Twisty. The problem is not present on laptops removed from the LAN. Another thought: a pattern has emerged wherein access to the server is generally fine in the morning and then goes out at around noon, possibly returning in the evening. This has caused me to believe that something else happening on the network is causing the instability (eg a coworker coming in and using another workstation). I'm going to try removing everything on the LAN except a single machine to test this hypothesis.

Comment: have you tried to see if your IP is [blacklisted](https://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check) by one of the NS routers